# Limit input checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to limit user's input checkbox fields selection.

In the code, the limit is informed in **var max=2**

I tried the code but did not works.

What is wrong?
I followed the same idea from http://jsfiddle.net/48BvH/1 but with no success.

```js
$("input[name=addon-3913-carnes]").change(function() {
  var max = 2;
  if ($("input[name=addon-3913-carnes]:checked").length == max) {
    $("input[name=addon-3913-carnes]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("input[name=addon-3913-carnes]").removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $("input[name=addon-3913-carnes]").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wc-pao-addon-container  wc-pao-addon wc-pao-addon-carnes" data-product-name="Marmitex">


  <label for="addon-3913-carnes-1" class="wc-pao-addon-name" data-addon-name="Carnes" data-has-per-person-pricing="" data-has-per-block-pricing="">Carnes </label>
  <div class="wc-pao-addon-description">
    <p>Escolha no máximo 3</p>
  </div>

  <p class="form-row form-row-wide wc-pao-addon-wrap wc-pao-addon-3913-carnes-1-0">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="wc-pao-addon-field wc-pao-addon-checkbox" name="addon-3913-carnes" data-raw-price="" data-price="" data-price-type="quantity_based" value="carne-assada" data-label="Carne Assada"> Carne Assada </label>
  </p>


  <p class="form-row form-row-wide wc-pao-addon-wrap wc-pao-addon-3913-carnes-1-1">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="wc-pao-addon-field wc-pao-addon-checkbox" name="addon-3913-carnes" data-raw-price="" data-price="" data-price-type="quantity_based" value="carne-cozida" data-label="Carne Cozida"> Carne Cozida </label>
  </p>


  <p class="form-row form-row-wide wc-pao-addon-wrap wc-pao-addon-3913-carnes-1-2">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="wc-pao-addon-field wc-pao-addon-checkbox" name="addon-3913-carnes" data-raw-price="" data-price="" data-price-type="quantity_based" value="frango-assado" data-label="Frango Assado"> Frango Assado </label>
  </p>


  <p class="form-row form-row-wide wc-pao-addon-wrap wc-pao-addon-3913-carnes-1-3">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="wc-pao-addon-field wc-pao-addon-checkbox" name="addon-3913-carnes" data-raw-price="" data-price="" data-price-type="quantity_based" value="frango-cozido" data-label="Frango Cozido"> Frango Cozido </label>
  </p>


  <p class="form-row form-row-wide wc-pao-addon-wrap wc-pao-addon-3913-carnes-1-4">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="wc-pao-addon-field wc-pao-addon-checkbox" name="addon-3913-carnes" data-raw-price="" data-price="" data-price-type="quantity_based" value="frango-frito" data-label="Frango Frito"> Frango Frito </label>
  </p>


  <p class="form-row form-row-wide wc-pao-addon-wrap wc-pao-addon-3913-carnes-1-5">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="wc-pao-addon-field wc-pao-addon-checkbox" name="addon-3913-carnes" data-raw-price="" data-price="" data-price-type="quantity_based" value="calabresa-assada" data-label="Calabresa Assada"> Calabresa Assada </label>
  </p>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When 2 inputs are selected, you are disabling all other inputs, then enabling them **all**. You should only enable those that are checked:

```js
$("input[name=addon-3913-carnes]").change(function() {
  var max = 2;
  if ($("input[name=addon-3913-carnes]:checked").length == max) {
    $("input[name=addon-3913-carnes]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("input[name=addon-3913-carnes]:checked").removeAttr('disabled'); // Here you should enable checked inputs only
  } else {
    $("input[name=addon-3913-carnes]").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wc-pao-addon-container  wc-pao-addon wc-pao-addon-carnes" data-product-name="Marmitex">


  <label for="addon-3913-carnes-1" class="wc-pao-addon-name" data-addon-name="Carnes" data-has-per-person-pricing="" data-has-per-block-pricing="">Carnes </label>
  <div class="wc-pao-addon-description">
    <p>Escolha no máximo 3</p>
  </div>

  <p class="form-row form-row-wide wc-pao-addon-wrap wc-pao-addon-3913-carnes-1-0">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="wc-pao-addon-field wc-pao-addon-checkbox" name="addon-3913-carnes" data-raw-price="" data-price="" data-price-type="quantity_based" value="carne-assada" data-label="Carne Assada"> Carne Assada </label>
  </p>


  <p class="form-row form-row-wide wc-pao-addon-wrap wc-pao-addon-3913-carnes-1-1">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="wc-pao-addon-field wc-pao-addon-checkbox" name="addon-3913-carnes" data-raw-price="" data-price="" data-price-type="quantity_based" value="carne-cozida" data-label="Carne Cozida"> Carne Cozida </label>
  </p>


  <p class="form-row form-row-wide wc-pao-addon-wrap wc-pao-addon-3913-carnes-1-2">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="wc-pao-addon-field wc-pao-addon-checkbox" name="addon-3913-carnes" data-raw-price="" data-price="" data-price-type="quantity_based" value="frango-assado" data-label="Frango Assado"> Frango Assado </label>
  </p>


  <p class="form-row form-row-wide wc-pao-addon-wrap wc-pao-addon-3913-carnes-1-3">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="wc-pao-addon-field wc-pao-addon-checkbox" name="addon-3913-carnes" data-raw-price="" data-price="" data-price-type="quantity_based" value="frango-cozido" data-label="Frango Cozido"> Frango Cozido </label>
  </p>


  <p class="form-row form-row-wide wc-pao-addon-wrap wc-pao-addon-3913-carnes-1-4">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="wc-pao-addon-field wc-pao-addon-checkbox" name="addon-3913-carnes" data-raw-price="" data-price="" data-price-type="quantity_based" value="frango-frito" data-label="Frango Frito"> Frango Frito </label>
  </p>


  <p class="form-row form-row-wide wc-pao-addon-wrap wc-pao-addon-3913-carnes-1-5">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="wc-pao-addon-field wc-pao-addon-checkbox" name="addon-3913-carnes" data-raw-price="" data-price="" data-price-type="quantity_based" value="calabresa-assada" data-label="Calabresa Assada"> Calabresa Assada </label>
  </p>


</div>
```